# Firebase: FIRApp.configure() keeps wanting me to change it to FirebaseApp.configure()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So I made a project that included lots of extra code so I could try out different things, and I am slowly copy-pasting the files from textedit into my new project.

I created a new Firebase account, added the google plist file, initialized and installed the pods needed (also changed the iOS version to 10.0 on the pod file)... yet it's still wanting me to use FirebaseApp.configure() instead of FIRApp.configure().

Should I just delete the whole thing and try again? I just created a new Xcode project, so if I had to delete it right now that would be fine.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        return true
    }
```

There hasn't been much code written, but I can't figure out what could have made this happen... especially since I just started the new project.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Firebase 3 vs Firebase 4. Some of the documentation hasn't been fully updated yet and new Pod installs will install 4. I just went through that myself. See [Migrate to the latest Firebase SDK for Swift (v4.0.0)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide)

Comment: @Jay's link is broken now. Here is the new one: [Migrate to the latest Firebase SDK for Swift (v4.0.0)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide)

Answer (score 8):

`FirebaseApp.configure()` is correct. I checked out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) just now and `FIRApp.configure()` has been renamed `FirebaseApp.configure()`. I also ran `pod update` on one of my projects just to confirm, and my project had me change to using `FirebaseApp.configure()`. So no need to rebuild!

Comment: It changed from FIRApp to FirebaseApp between Firebase iOS SDK 3.x and 4.x

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that `FIRApp.configure()` can be changed to `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Answer (score 0):

In firebase it suggest to add the following to app delegate:

> "
>
> import UIKit import Firebase
>
> @UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder,
>   UIApplicationDelegate {
>
> var window: UIWindow?
>
> func application(_ application: UIApplication,
>       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
>       -> Bool {
>       **FirebaseApp.configure()**
>       return true   } }
>
> "

This includes the **FirebaseApp.configure()** command